# redirect_uri_mismatch in Google APIs in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, google-api, google-api-client, google-api-dotnet-client

I am trying to upload video on my YouTube channel using ASP.NET Web Form. I created developer account and [tested it working using JavaScript based solution](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/tree/master/javascript) which requires login every-time to upload a video.

I want users of my website to upload video directly on my channel and every auth should be in code behind, user should not be prompted to login. For this I wrote following class:

```
public class UploadVideo
{
    public async Task Run(string filePath)
    {
        string CLIENT_ID = "1111111111111111111111.apps.googleusercontent.com";
        string CLIENT_SECRET = "234JEjkwkdfh1111";
        var youtubeService = AuthenticateOauth(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, "SingleUser");

        var video = new Video();
        video.Snippet = new VideoSnippet();
        video.Snippet.Title = "Default Video Title";
        video.Snippet.Description = "Default Video Description";
        video.Snippet.Tags = new string[] { "tag1", "tag2" };
        video.Snippet.CategoryId = "22"; // See https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories/list
        video.Status = new VideoStatus();
        video.Status.PrivacyStatus = "unlisted"; // or "private" or "public"

        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
        {
            var videosInsertRequest = youtubeService.Videos.Insert(video, "snippet,status", fileStream, "video/*");
            videosInsertRequest.ProgressChanged += videosInsertRequest_ProgressChanged;
            videosInsertRequest.ResponseReceived += videosInsertRequest_ResponseReceived;

            await videosInsertRequest.UploadAsync();
        }
    }

    void videosInsertRequest_ProgressChanged(Google.Apis.Upload.IUploadProgress progress)
    {
        switch (progress.Status)
        {
            case UploadStatus.Uploading:
                //Console.WriteLine("{0} bytes sent.", progress.BytesSent);
                break;

            case UploadStatus.Failed:
                //Console.WriteLine("An error prevented the upload from completing.\n{0}", progress.Exception);
                break;
        }
    }

    void videosInsertRequest_ResponseReceived(Video video)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Video id '{0}' was successfully uploaded.", video.Id);
    }

    public static YouTubeService AuthenticateOauth(string clientId, string clientSecret, string userName)
    {

        string[] scopes = new string[] { YouTubeService.Scope.Youtube,  // view and manage your YouTube account
                                         YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeForceSsl,
                                         YouTubeService.Scope.Youtubepartner,
                                         YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubepartnerChannelAudit,
                                         YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeReadonly,
                                         YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeUpload};

        try
        {
            // here is where we Request the user to give us access, or use the Refresh Token that was previously stored in %AppData%
            UserCredential credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(new ClientSecrets { ClientId = clientId, ClientSecret = clientSecret }
                                                                                         , scopes
                                                                                         , userName
                                                                                         , CancellationToken.None
                                                                                         , new FileDataStore("Daimto.YouTube.Auth.Store")).Result;

            YouTubeService service = new YouTubeService(new YouTubeService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = "YouTube Data API Sample",
            });
            return service;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Now using this class into Page_Load() of default.aspx, as given below:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string path = "C:/Users/abhi/Desktop/TestClip.mp4";
        new UploadVideo().Run(path).Wait();
    }
    catch (AggregateException ex)
    {
        //catch exceptions
    }
}
```

When I run this (default.aspx) page, i see http://localhost:29540/default.aspx spins, so I used them on Google Developer Console as given below:

[image]

Upon running http://localhost:29540/default.aspx opens a new tab which displays "redirect_uri_mismatch" error as given below:

[image]

At this point if I look in browser address, I see redirect_uri is set to http://localhost:37294/authorize and I just manually change this to http://localhost:29540/default.aspx which generates a token.

So, can you suggest where to make changes in above code so that request uri fills up correctly from my app side.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A day waste then I came to know below redirect URL is working for all localhost web applications. So you need to use below URL on google developer console web application's "Authorized redirect URIs".

```
http://localhost/authorize/
```

Comment: Thank to you I realized that sometimes you must put "/" at the end of the URL and other times no. I lost some hours because this silliness.

Answer (score 2):

For anybody still having this issue in 2022, I figured out a solution. If you are using https://localhost:portnumb as your redirect uri, just use https://127.0.0.1:sameportnumb as your redirect uri. It ended up working for me

Answer (score 0):

try to configure https://localhost:7050/signin-google using  your port number in your api console in google

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your answer. Please provide more details about your solution. Code snippets, high quality descriptions, or any relevant information would be great. Clear and concise answers are more helpful and easier to understand for everyone. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77045362/edit) your answer with specifics to raise the quality of your answer. For more information: [How To: Write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Happy coding!